# selecting data from a table in database php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get the data from a table in my database and store it into a textfield named "about"

however i keep getting an error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in

```
<?php
require("common.php");     
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM about");     
$result = $query or die(mysql_error()); // run the query    
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch a result row      
echo $row['about'];    
?>
```

Comment: sorry i pressed enter and instantly realised - it has been edited

Comment: What is the table name?

Comment: table is "about" field being "content" there is only one field at the moment, im pretty new so trying to do it one step at a time before adding further parameters to go into individual fields.

Comment: `$db->prepare` prepare is object of instance pdo?

Comment: Change the select to `SELECT content FROM about` and your echo to `echo $row['content'];`

Comment: @juergend but the error he is getting is not due to what you are saying.and he is already using '*' so whats the point of explicitly use content in select.

Comment: @RishabhRaj: That part is not so important, but afterwards he tries to select `about` which is the table name and not the column.

Comment: @juergend you are right but when i saw it was content ,i think the question was updated or i overlooked something.

Comment: @juergend just to be clear - the table in my database is "about" and the field in my database is "content" however the textfield of which i want the information to be put into is "about" which is why i had it as $row['about'] - i have tried the way you have stated and i still receive the same error

Comment: @user2987509: All this confusion and guessing is the result of an incomplete question. Please add all necessary info in future questions. That way you get a good, quality answer.

Comment: @juergend yes apologies... this is literally the first time i have used this site, but i now know for future reference to make myself more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because you are not executing your query.after Prepare use Execute().your code will look something like this

```
<?php
require("common.php"); 
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM about");  
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);//to check the elements of the array
echo $row['content'];    
?>
```

Remember

```
PDO::prepare() - Prepares a statement for execution and returns a statement object
PDOStatement::execute() - Executes a prepared statement
```

Comment: thanks, i originally had "$result = execute($query);" but it gave me a fatal error so i removed! Although now I have added that it still get the same error.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: try like this $result = $query->execute();

Comment: error is the exact same: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in

Comment: @user2987509 have u written the $result the same way i have written in comment?

Comment: since changing to: $result = $query->execute();

i get: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @user2987509 i updated my answer have a look

Comment: The error has now gone :) thanks very much!

Comment: @user2987509 your welcome.:) enjoy coding..have a good day.

Comment: i dont know why i got a downvote for my answer ,if i get the reason than i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `mysql_query();`. This to execute your sql query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM about";     
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: if you are using PDO please stick to it and mysql_* are deprecated ,please dont use that.